# reducing fractions with combinations and powers of large integers

Tags: fractions

For example, I'm trying to reduce $\frac{49 \choose6}{49^6}$. Is there anyway to reduce this fraction further? Thanks

Comment: If you know combination formula, you could reduce the fraction.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the formula to express the $49 \choose 6$ in terms of factorials.  In this specific case, the denominator is $7^{12}$ so you only care about powers of $7$ in the numerator.  Using [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) you can find that $49 \choose 6$ has a factor $7^2$ so you can divide that out.  But is $$\frac {\frac 1{49}{49 \choose 6}}{49^5}$$ more enlightening than your expression?  Simplification is in the eye of the beholder and yours prompts me to think of a lottery that draws six numbers of $49$.